# Can Lightning Actions be added to Object tabs?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction, summer-17

Until Standard buttons like `New` can be overriden with Lightning components with the Summer '17 release I need an alternative working now.[image]

**How can I add a Lightning action to tab/list views in Lightning?**

Comment: Short story ,Quick actions cannot be added there while you can create a visualforce page list button and should still show up there

Comment: Is it on the roadmap then?